# swagger for an already created project

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I just found [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node) and I have installed all of the dependencies.

Now I have a `REST` `express` api at `/var/www/myApi` this has already been created but needs documentation.

However no where in the documentation does it state how to use an already existing project with swagger.

I am able to create a new project and run it, but how do I use an existing project?

Comment: I don't think you can generate a swagger spec from node.js code.  I believe it only generates an API spec from Java code that follows the JAX-RS format (using swagger-core).  I believe that swagger-node is a generator that uses a swagger spec to generate node.js code.